# deserialize and serialize data in mysql

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Is there any way for deserialize and serialize data in mysql without using php and just using SQL language?

working on woocommerce plugin that stores cart items as serialized in database.
The goal is to make a query to cart table and fetch cart items and then send the result to an API.
cart items are stored as serialized data in table that is like :

```
a:1:{s:4:"cart";a:2:{s:32:"76dc611d6ebaafc66cc0879c71b5db5c";a:11:{s:3:"key";s:32:"76dc611d6ebaafc66cc0879c71b5db5c";s:10:"product_id";i:128;s:12:"variation_id";i:0;s:9:"variation";a:0:{}s:8:"quantity";i:1;s:9:"data_hash";s:32:"b5c1d5ca8bae6d4896cf1807cdf763f0";s:13:"line_tax_data";a:2:{s:8:"subtotal";a:0:{}s:5:"total";a:0:{}}s:13:"line_subtotal";d:500;s:17:"line_subtotal_tax";i:0;s:10:"line_total";d:500;s:8:"line_tax";i:0;}s:32:"65ded5353c5ee48d0b7d48c591b8f430";a:6:{s:3:"key";s:32:"65ded5353c5ee48d0b7d48c591b8f430";s:10:"product_id";i:132;s:12:"variation_id";i:0;s:9:"variation";a:0:{}s:8:"quantity";i:1;s:9:"data_hash";s:32:"b5c1d5ca8bae6d4896cf1807cdf763f0";}}}
```

and after deserializing it in online tools I get this stucture:

```
Array
  (
   [cart] => Array
    (
        [76dc611d6ebaafc66cc0879c71b5db5c] => Array
            (
                [key] => 76dc611d6ebaafc66cc0879c71b5db5c
                [product_id] => 128
                [variation_id] => 0
                [variation] => Array
                    (
                    )

                [quantity] => 1
                [data_hash] => b5c1d5ca8bae6d4896cf1807cdf763f0
                [line_tax_data] => Array
                    (
                        [subtotal] => Array
                            (
                            )

                        [total] => Array
                            (
                            )

                    )

                [line_subtotal] => 500
                [line_subtotal_tax] => 0
                [line_total] => 500
                [line_tax] => 0
            )

        [65ded5353c5ee48d0b7d48c591b8f430] => Array
            (
                [key] => 65ded5353c5ee48d0b7d48c591b8f430
                [product_id] => 132
                [variation_id] => 0
                [variation] => Array
                    (
                    )

                [quantity] => 1
                [data_hash] => b5c1d5ca8bae6d4896cf1807cdf763f0
            )

      )

  )
```

each of this object properites is needed to be accessed and store in a columns and then sending the result of query to an API.

How could deserialize these data in SQL language?

Comment: (De)Serialize what? Please provide sample data and desired results.

Comment: I added more details about it. Hope it is clear now.

Comment: You're storing data in a format that's both unstructured and specific to PHP, thus neglecting the benefits of using a relational database that can speak SQL. It'd be the equivalent of finding text in pictures of books. I'm sure you can write an unserializer in MySQL if you spend enough time but it'd probably be a pretty suboptimal investment, esp. when you still need a language to create the API server and you already have PHP available.

Comment: Since your database is not the one that will send the data to an API, the deserialization should just be done by PHP when it queries the data and then transforms that in an API call.

Answer (score 3):

I have been struggling with a similar issue: Deserialising and serialising data from table wp_postmeta, to do search-and-replace on certain parts of it (I'm translating WooCommerce-sites and I would prefer to do it all within MySQL, rather than using PHP). In my case, the search-and-replace always happened on the fourth s-element. I developed a sproc for this. It probably doesn't suit your exact use case, but maybe it's close enough for adapting it to your needs:

```
CREATE DEFINER=`strompf`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `replace_serial`(
        in table_name_in            tinytext,   # Source table name
        in col_serial_data_src_in   tinytext,   # Column with source serialised data
        in col_serial_data_dst_in   tinytext,   # Column with destination serialised data
        in col_src_in               tinytext,   # Column with source text strings
        in col_dst_in               tinytext    # Column with desination text string
    )
BEGIN
#
# Find-and-replace in element s4 within serialised content
################################################################################
#
# * This sproc "replace_serial" needs as input pointers to a table 
#   ("pointer table") with the following columns:
#   * Column with the source serialised data
#   * Column for storing the updated serialised data
#   * Column with find-string
#   * Column with replace-strings
# * It can be any table: The arguments for replace_serial() contains the name
#   of this table and the names of those four columns
# * Internally, data from this input-table is copied to temporary table 
#   "serial_tmp"
# * The designated serialised data is decomposed into several fields (again,
#   in table "serial_tmp") - Currently, this sproc only works for serialised 
#   data with 1 a-element, followed by 6 s-elements. This sproc has not been 
#   tested with other configurations
# * Find-and-replace is only performed on element s4 (=the 4th s-element)
# * Subsequently, the new length of s4 is calculated, and the serialised string
#   is written to the designated column in the "pointer table"
# * Subsequently, it's up to the programmer to process the resulting data in
#   the pointer table
# * This approach with a "pointer table" works really well: Easy to grasp,
#   flexible and easy to debug. It's especially handy for debugging or further
#   processing that the output is in a separate column from the input.
# * Copyright Jeroen Strompf - De Vliegende Brigade - 2021.03.09
#
#
# History
########################################
#
# * 2021.03.09: Created, tested and pushed to "bal_dwh_org"
#
#
################################################################################
# Define working table "serial_tmp"
################################################################################
#
drop table if exists 
    serial_tmp;
create temporary table
    serial_tmp
    (
        serial_data_src     varchar(255)    comment "Actual serialised data",   
        serial_data_dst     varchar(255)    comment "Resulting serialised data. This is a separate field, to make debugging easier",
        find_string         varchar(255)    comment "String to be found within serial_data_src",
        replace_string      varchar(255)    comment "Replacement string for within serial_data_src, resulting in serial_data_dst",

        a_len           smallint,
        a_string        varchar(255)    comment "The string within the accolade",
        s1              varchar(255)    comment "Complete s-part, including length statement and string",
        s2              varchar(255),
        s3              varchar(255),
        s4              varchar(255)    comment "Complete s4-string",
        s4_len_src      smallint        comment "Original length of s4",
        s4_string_src   varchar(255)    comment "Original s4 string",
        s4_len_dst      smallint        comment "New length",
        s4_string_dst   varchar(255)    comment "New string",
        s5              varchar(255),
        s6              varchar(255)
    );


################################################################################
# Copy working data to working table
################################################################################
#
set @ddl=concat
(
    "insert into serial_tmp 
    (
        serial_data_src,
        find_string,
        replace_string
    )
    select ",
        col_serial_data_src_in, ", ",
        col_src_in, ", ",
        col_dst_in, " ",
    "from ",
        table_name_in, ";"
);

prepare stmt from @ddl;
execute stmt;
deallocate prepare stmt;


################################################################################
# Decompose serialsed data
################################################################################
#
# Leading a-field
########################################
#
update
    serial_tmp
set
    a_len       = substring_index(substring_index(serial_data_src, ":", 2), ":", -1),
    a_string    = substring_index(substring_index(serial_data_src, "}",1), "{", -1);


# Complete s-fields
########################################
#
update
    serial_tmp
set
    s1 = substring_index(a_string, ";", 1),
    s2 = substring_index(substring_index(a_string, ";", 2), ";", -1),
    s3 = substring_index(substring_index(a_string, ";", 3), ";", -1),
    s4 = substring_index(substring_index(a_string, ";", 4), ";", -1),
    s5 = substring_index(substring_index(a_string, ";", 5), ";", -1),
    s6 = substring_index(substring_index(a_string, ";", 6), ";", -1);


# Further decompose s4
########################################
#
update
    serial_tmp
set
    s4_len_src      = substring_index(substring_index(s4, ":", 2), ":", -1),
    s4_string_src   = substring_index(substring_index(s4, '"', 2), '"', -1);


################################################################################
# Find-and-replace
################################################################################
#
# Finally! The heart of the matter
#
update
    serial_tmp
set
    s4_string_dst   =   replace(s4_string_src, find_string, replace_string),
    s4_len_dst      =   length(s4_string_dst);


################################################################################
# Reassemble
################################################################################
#
update
    serial_tmp
set
    serial_data_dst = concat
    (
        "a:",a_len, ":",
        "{",
            s1, ";", s2, ";", s3, ";",
            "s:",s4_len_dst,":",
            char(34),
                s4_string_dst,
            char(34),
            ";", s5, ";", s6, ";",
        "}"
    );


################################################################################
# Copy results back to the original input table
################################################################################
#
# * Fill in the result in column "col_serial_data_dst_in"
#
set @ddl2=concat
(
    "update ", table_name_in, " 
    join 
       serial_tmp
       on
       serial_tmp.serial_data_src = ", table_name_in, ".",col_serial_data_src_in," 
    set
       ",table_name_in, ".",col_serial_data_dst_in, " = serial_tmp.serial_data_dst;"
);

prepare stmt from @ddl2;
execute stmt;
deallocate prepare stmt;

END
```

Answer (score 1):

`serialize` PHP function serializes a data structure into a string representation that's **unique** to PHP and can be reversed into a PHP object using unserialize.

MySQL doesn't know what a PHP serialization is. You can't do it using just SQL.

Comment: how about this link?
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/dev/mysql-server/latest/group__serialize__api.html#details

Is there any function in mysql to do this task?

Comment: @zahra_oveyedzade That documentation is not for MySQL end users, it belongs to the MySQL source code written in C and/or C++. If you're willing to write C code perhaps you could create a PHP extension (PHP is written in C).

Comment: as @ÁlvaroGonzález said the only way to do this in the database layer is by extending MySQL for your requirements